# How want to add 1 for a serialcode

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

Last record is `PC101` and I want to select `PC102`

I used the `SUBSTRING` function to seperate `PC` AND `101` and added 1 to it and this worked.

The problem is when the serialcode is `PC076`, then the result becomes `PC77`, but the expected result is `PC077`

How can I change my function so the *zero* doesn't get lost?

```
DECLARE @zimmetno as varchar(50) 
SELECT @zimmetno = BilgisayarZimmetNo FROM K_TANITIMKARTI
SELECT CONVERT (varchar,SUBSTRING(@zimmetno, 1, 2)  ) + CONVERT (varchar,SUBSTRING(@zimmetno, 3, 3) + 1  )
```

[image: sql serialcode that i want to select (serialcode + 1)]

Comment: What happens after `PC999'?

Comment: Do not store string prefix in the value, add it in the query.

Comment: Thank you t.niese i was working on SQL i added LPAD function on my server and it worked well.Stefan Wuebbe PC999 record is so much i cant reach that data